# How do I access another model's database to carry out some calculation in my current model field in Django?

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, django, django-models

First of all, this [sample project is available](https://github.com/codervoder/rough.git) here in order for anyone to take a look at it and let me know where I am going wrong.

I have two models, Package and Receivables there. In Package, there is a field total_package and in Receivables, there are two fields initially, discount and approved_package. I want to access total_package and from that I want to subtract discount to auto-populate approved_package field. If you look into the project's test.js file, I tried to achieve the same using JS, but that doesn't fulfil my intention. I do not know where I went wrong there. I also want to learn how I can achieve that using pure django way. Can someone help me?

The models:

```
class Package(models.Model):
    rt_number=ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=CASCADE)
    diagnosis=models.ForeignKey(Diagnosis, on_delete=CASCADE)
    treatment=ForeignKey(Treatment, on_delete=CASCADE)
    patient_type=ForeignKey(PatientType, on_delete=CASCADE)
    date_of_admission=models.DateField(default=None)
    max_fractions=models.IntegerField(default=None)
    total_package=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

class Receivables(models.Model):
    rt_number=ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=CASCADE)
    discount=models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, default=None)
    approved_package=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=None)
    proposed_fractions=models.IntegerField()
    done_fractions=models.IntegerField()
    base_value=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    expected_value=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

Hope to receive some help with this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both class you have a common field what is it rt_number. So you can set a property to get a Package object from the Receivable model class and use it to calculate or whatever you want to do.

In Recivables class:

```py
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist, MultipleObjectsReturned

class Receivables(models.Model):
    rt_number=ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=CASCADE) # This is the common field in both class
    .....

    @property
    def package(self):
        """Return a package object or None if not exists"""
        try:
            return Package.objects.get(rt_number=self.rt_number)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return None
        except MultipleObjectsReturned:
            # You'll need to write some code to know what package to use
            # By example, return last Package
            return Package.objects.filter(rt_number=self.rt_number).last()

    
    def calculate_aproved_discount(self):
        """Calculates the discount taken the package as reference"""
        if(self.package):
            # make here your calculations
            return self.package.total_package - self.discount
        else: # package does not exists
            # You can not calculate the approved package
            return 0 # or whatever you want in these case

    # Overrides django model save method to autocalculate the discount when object is saved
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.aproved_package = self.calculate_aproved_discount() # Calculate aproved_discount field
        super(Receivables, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # call save in ancestror
```

Also, I think your total_package should not be part of the model fields and should be a simple method or property (like decorated def package), and calculate it only when needed and not every time you save the object. But may be in your requirements you need to store it for some reason. And, this is important, if a Patient can only have one Package model association, change rt_number foreing keys for one to one relationship.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wrote the methods and I changed the rt_number foreignkeys to OneToOneField. I commanded makemigrations and that worked fine. But when I tried to migrate, 'django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: new__account_package.rt_number_id' shows up in the terminal. You can see the changes in the github link I provided in my post initially.

Comment: Ok, deal with migrations requires you read a lot about how to apply it and deal with this kind of problems in different environments. So forget OneToOne relationship and write back as ForeingKey again. The problem with ForeingKey is that could return several Package objects for Patient, no problem with that, but in the case you must write some code to choose one of them. I edited the example to rewrite package attribute taking into account that Package could return more than one object.

Comment: Thanks. It does work now. But I just found out that it is totally hardcoded. I mean no matter what amount I enter in approved_package, it, by default, performs the calculations and saves the result in the database, but what I wanted was that when a user enters amount in discount field, the approved_package field should have an initial value that is returned by the calculation but the user should be able to change that. How can I do that, if that's not too much to ask for? Sorry for not being clear, earlier with my question.

Comment: Read about model fields. You can set a default value, it can be a expression or a harcoded value or call a method to resolve, this default value will be presented to the user when create a new object, also the user can change this value, and also the user data, can be intercepted in the save method and apply, reject or  calculate other different discount. I think I answered your initial question :) Finally, is better to extract all the business logic outside the models and focus your models just in data storage and ask thing like discounts to other classes or functions outside the model

Comment: Noted. Will do that. Thanks again for your time and help. :)

Comment: Hi @DVicenteR, It would be really great if you could please look into this issue and give some suggestion, if possible. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68391168/how-to-set-autocomplete-on-django-foreignkey-field

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to access the corresponding Package object's total_package from the Package's foreign key. Then you can perform the calculation as you want.
Like if r1 is a Receivables object and it is linked to the Package Object by a foreign key, then we can do something like this.

```
r1.approved_package = r1.package.total_package - r1.discount
r1.save()
```

Note - Before doing this make sure r1 is linked to the Package object